# Programmatically remove custom attributes from existing assemblies

Tags: .net, clr, .net-assembly

I am using System.Reflection.Emit to create a new assembly A that calls methods from an existing assembly B.

The methods in B are annotated with some custom attributes and I want to remove them programmatically. I do not have access to source code that generated B.

I could not find a documented way in .NET framework to do this. Any pointers?

Thanks a ton !

Comment: By "remove them" I assume you mean "generate an assembly whose metadata and IL is identical to the target assembly, except for those attributes I find distateful, and then possibly replace the target assembly"? That can certainly be done (just disassemble, remove attributes, and reassemble,) though only if the assembly has not been signed with a strong name.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I want and my assembly does not have a strong name. Can I disassemble an assembly programmatically just using the .NET framework libraries?

Comment: You have to decompile the assembly with ildasm.exe, remove the IL for the attribute, put humpty-dumpty back together with ilasm.exe.  Doing this programmatically is, erm, not entirely impossible.

Comment: You may want to look at Mono Cecil: http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil

Answer (score 3):

You can look into [PowerShellArsenal](https://github.com/mattifestation/PowerShellArsenal/blob/master/README.md).
It has a script for removing SuppressIldasmAttribute.

I haven't looked at it, but I would guess you can use the code used for that to remove just about any attribute.

> Remove-AssemblySuppressIldasmAttribute
>
> Strips a SuppressIldasmAttribute attribute from a .NET assembly.

It uses [dnlib](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnlib) to [remove](https://github.com/mattifestation/PowerShellArsenal/blob/fa095cd1fe01a4850943d67bc250e70dffae8602/MalwareAnalysis/dotNetMalwareAnalysis.ps1#L499) an attribute.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that is possible.  Attributes are compiled into IL.  Removing them programmatically would be like trying to remove a method or property programmatically.

Comment: "Removing them programmatically would be like trying to remove a method or property programmatically" and what is so far-fetched about this? Ever heard of Mono Cecil?

Comment: By "programmatically" I mean changing a class at runtime and then using the modified class at runtime.  Can Mono Cecil do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit an existing assembly with [Mono.Cecil](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/).

For example, to remove `SuppressIldasmAttribute`:

```
public static void RemoveSuppressIldasmAttribute(string input, string output)
{
    AssemblyDefinition assembly = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(input);

    foreach (CustomAttribute attribute in assembly.CustomAttributes)
    {
        if (attribute.Constructor.DeclaringType.Name == "SuppressIldasmAttribute")
        {
            assembly.CustomAttributes.Remove(attribute);
        }
    }

    assembly.Write(output);
}
```